# Android emulator/virtual device unauthorized

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to use android emulator but everytime I run adb devices I get emulator unauthorized. 
I wiped data, did cold boot and even deleted the device and downloaded a new one.
[The screenshot after running adb devices.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUXj6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, killing and restarting the adb server will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run Android Studio as **Administrator**...this should work